# Inkscape Stroke Does Not Follow Path Outline

Tags: inkscape, path

I'm somewhat new to vector graphics, but this is really baffling to me.

When I make a shape, the lines are supposed to follow the path outline, right? According to the outline I should have a niceish rounded square. Instead the lines inexplicably distort outward. What is going on here and how do I make it stop?

[image: path does not follow path outline]

Comment: Have you perhaps added a path effect? Click your rectangle once to select it, then open the Path menu. Go down to the bottom and click 'Remove Path Effect'. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @user287001 Unfortunately, 'remove path effect' does nothing.  I put together an [imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/gMCHE) showing step by step what I'm doing with a new rectangle.

Comment: It is doing this with all of my pencil drawn shapes. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by having the `LPE based interactive simplify` button selected in the Pencil Tool options along the top.  If you don't want to use that feature, then switch it off.  With the feature on, it applies a Simplify path effect.

[image: Screenshot of Penicl Tool Options]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can turn this off for existing lines? Or will it only apply to new shapes that I draw?

Comment: Yes, you can select the path and then click Path > Remove Path Effect.